# How to change Cloud Platform Project of a container-bound script programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an automated Google Apps Script where I have a template Google Sheet where it has a container-bound script connected to specific Cloud Platform Project (Standard Project).

When I copy the sheet programmatically, the container-bound script is copied correctly. However, the container-bound script is assigned to a dynamic Cloud Platform Project.

Is there a way using Google Apps Script APIs to change the Cloud Platform Project from code?

Comment: Ideally when you need the document copy's script to belong to a specific cloud project, you would be using an add on (rather than bound script) to avoid duplication of the script project in the first place.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the exact same problem. If not, what else did you try, or what worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue